# Take action on negative exit from where - Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I have a manual in which I check if I can install the agent, what I would like to do and the following, when there is an ignored one in mine where, for example, where I check if there is a `/opt/Agent/` directory, otherwise I would like to create this directory, how to do this?

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:

  - name: 'Ensure that free space on /opt/Agent/ is grater than 1.5GB'
    assert:
      that: item.size_available >= 1500000000
      msg: 'disk space has reached 1.5GB threshold'
    when: item.mount == mountname
    with_items: '{{ ansible_mounts }}'

  - name: Ansible check agent is present.
    stat:
      path: /etc/init.d/agent
    register: file_details

  - debug:
      msg: "Agent is present"
    when: file_details.stat.exists

  - name: Ansible check directory Agent exists.
    stat:
      path: /opt/Agent/
    register: files_to_delete

  - debug:
      msg: "Directory Agent exists"
    when: files_to_delete.stat.exists and files_to_delete.stat.isdir

  vars:
    mountname: '/opt/Agent/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the "file" module to make sure the directory exists, or otherwise, create it.

```
---
- name: over
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
   - name: makes sure directory exists or creates it
     file:
       state: directory
       path: /opt/Agent
```

If you use this task, then you can avoid all those verifications that only work to "make sure" the path exists.

Comment: got it, thanks for the answer, a doubt, if you want to close the playbook when a condition has not been met, how to do?

Comment: You could use a task with the "meta" module with the "end_play" in combination with a "when" statement.